# How to Iterate through Collection without knowing the keys? and Later save those keys

Tags: c++, json, dictionary, tree, jsoncpp

My goal is to extract column heads from a Json file converted from a normal table in CSV (Excel sheet) using **C++**. I am using Visual Studio 2022 IDE.

My Json file looks like this

```
{
  "people" : [
    {
       "firstName": "Joe",
       "lastName": "Jackson",
       "gender": "male",
       "age": 28,
       "number": "7349282382"
    },
    {
       "firstName": "James",
       "lastName": "Smith",
       "gender": "male",
       "age": 32,
       "number": "5678568567"
    },
    {
       "firstName": "Emily",
       "lastName": "Jones",
       "gender": "female",
       "age": 24,
       "number": "456754675"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using [`JsonCpp`](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) library for parsing.

So the goal here is to **extract the column heads of the table** (*keys like "firstname","lastname" etc. in the given Json file*) **without knowing any of the keys** (*like if I use any other json file of same format but with different content*).

Here is a snippet of my code

```
fstream file("smallTabularJson.json");

    Json::Reader reader;            //creating reader that will be used to parse
    Json::Value data;           //creating collection that will hold the parsed data

    reader.parse(file, data);       //parsing data from file and storing in 'data'
```

Here I have parsed the content of Json file into a collection named 'data'

The approach I am trying is

> Since the json file looks like a STL Map, I will treat 'data' as a Map.

> Create a map iterator to access the key "people" (without explicitly mentioning it) and go to its value which is an Array.

> Go inside Array[0].

> It is again an map then create another iterator to access its keys one by one and save every key into an vector.

> Print the Vector.

But the problem is that the 'data' is not a Map. So when I tried this -

```
map<string, string>::iterator itr = data.begin();
```

It throws this error -

```
Error Code: E0312   
no suitable user-defined conversion from "Json::Value::iterator" to "std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string, std::string>>>>" exists    jsonFileRead3 "link to my directory"
```

Which means that 'data' is not a Map but Tree instead.

Please suggest how I can I convert 'data' from Tree to a Map, or if there is any other function inside JsonCpp library to get the keys. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map<string, string>::iterator` is specific to `map<string, string>`. A `Json::Value` has some conceptual similarities to that container, but it is not the same thing.

`data.begin()` is a [ValueIterator](https://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_value_iterator.html). For short, you can write

```
auto itr = data.begin()
```

And it will use the actual type of `itr`. An important thing here is to note that `Json::ValueIterator` has the following methods:

Its `key` method returns a `Json::Value` that in your case will be a string representing the name of the key.

If you want to get that as a `std::string`, you can use

```
itr.key().asString();
```

Its unary `operator*` method returns a reference to the `Json::Value` that is the value present at the key, which in your case will be of array type, which will need to be handled appropriately.

Comment: With the help of this, I am able to get the root key, any suggestion on how can I go 1 level down and get to keys "firstName","lastName"etc. ?

Comment: Those keys are two levels down, not one level down. As I mentioned, `*itr` is a `Json::Value` of array type, which itself can be iterated over. Going further, `(*itr)[0]` is a `Json::Value` of object type and itself can be iterated over... Does that point you in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks @Nathan Pierson I figured it out before reading your comment, and yes I did the same.